# How to save unwatered croton? Nothing seems working:(

Tags: indoors, plant-care, watering

It happened that I couldnt water my croton for quite long, about 20 days. We had it for about 15 years, so it was almost like a small tree. After such lomg period without water it looks really bad, leaves are hanging down, many have already fell off. I am wrapping wet cotton around the branches and next to leaves bunches, sprinkle the plant with water all the time, place air moisturizer next to it, but it does seem to revive. Is there any tips how to save those leaves which are not fully dead? Maybe hot bath? And if all leaves fall off how to make the new ones grow faster, if possible.
Thank you for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can or should do to try stop drought affected leaves from dying back. If the roots haven't been completely killed by drought, you may find new shoots starting to grow at soil level, so just keep the pot watered as necessary, but not soaking wet, water only when the surface of the soil feels dry to the  touch, not at all  if the soil doesn't feel dry on the surface, and wait and see what happens. If nothing starts into growth after 2-3 months, you can assume the roots are dead and the plant is no more...

Comment: New leaves only at soil level? It just has lots of branches, as it is an really old plant. Looked like a real small tree. Couldnt the new buds be on the branches?

Comment: Possible, yes, depends whether the stems have died back to the root or not - but don't  try to save dying leaves, just wait to see what grows, then cut back to  where  new growth is, if you get some.

Comment: Thank you. I think the stems didnt die, next to the leaves they look green. Still tried to save, sprinkled them a lot, and  looks like several leaves retirned to life. But not many:(